# Sum of elements in a matrix using threads in c

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, matrix

The problem statement goes like this: Calculate the sum of the elements in a bidimensional matrix, using a *separate thread* to calculate the sum of ***each row***. The main thread adds up these sums printing the final result.

From what I have seen so far, the code runs correctly. The only issue is when I choose the number of rows to be *smaller* than the number of columns (e.g. rows = 2, columns = 3), because it only computes the sum for the first 2 columns, completely ignoring the third one.

This is the code I wrote in C and I would really appreciate any help understanding what I did wrong or missed. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define M 10
#define N 10

int rows, columns, a[M][N], s[M];

// compute the sum of each row

void* f(void* p) {
   int k = *((int*) p);
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
      s[i] += a[k][i];
   }
   return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int i, j, *p, rc;
    int sum = 0;
    pthread_t th[M];

    // matrix creation
    printf("no. of rows = ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("no. of columns = ");
    scanf("%d", &columns);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = \n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe matrix is: \n");
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < columns; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    }

    // thread creation
    for (i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p = i;
        rc = pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, f, p);
        if (rc != 0) {
            printf("Thread creation failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        pthread_join(th[i], NULL);
    }
    // compute the final sum
    for (i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        sum += s[i];
    }
    printf("The sum is = %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
s[k] += a[k][i];
```

instead of

```
s[i] += a[k][i];
```

Sum of each rows should be added up in each index of each `row` as `s` is declared as `s[M]`.